Upgrading to bigger disk in a RAID1 mdadm array
My question is similar to Doing a disk copy with dd on RAID1 devices on Ubuntu but I need to change them for bigger disks.
I need to replace my actual 2TB disks in mdadm RAID1 with new 2 4TB disks, i'm using XFS.
Is it possible to use the accepted answer method for adding larger disks?
This is my current partition scheme:
nvme3n1     259:6    0   1.7T  0 disk  
├─nvme3n1p1 259:7    0   256M  0 part  
│ └─md0       9:0    0 255.9M  0 raid1 /boot/efi
├─nvme3n1p2 259:8    0     1G  0 part  
│ └─md1       9:1    0  1022M  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme3n1p3 259:9    0     1G  0 part  
│ └─md2       9:2    0  1022M  0 raid1 /boot
└─nvme3n1p4 259:10   0   1.7T  0 part  
  └─md3       9:3    0   1.7T  0 raid1 /
nvme2n1     259:11   0   1.7T  0 disk  
├─nvme2n1p1 259:12   0   256M  0 part  
│ └─md0       9:0    0 255.9M  0 raid1 /boot/efi
├─nvme2n1p2 259:13   0     1G  0 part  
│ └─md1       9:1    0  1022M  0 raid1 [SWAP]
├─nvme2n1p3 259:14   0     1G  0 part  
│ └─md2       9:2    0  1022M  0 raid1 /boot
└─nvme2n1p4 259:15   0   1.7T  0 part  
  └─md3       9:3    0   1.7T  0 raid1 /

I tought I could just proceed like this:

Attach the disks and partition them like the actual ones, even if they are bigger
Add the 2 new disks to the array and sync them
Install grub on the new disks
Remove the old one from the array and boot on the new ones.
Resize the new disks last partition with xfs_growfs to fill the remaining space.

Would it work?
Also, is there any way to use this method in case I would like to grow a partition which is not the last, let's say the SWAP one? If I create the final partitions with the new sizes before adding the new disks to mdadm, would that work? Does it syncs them by just looking at the partitions regardless of the new bigger size? So the list becomes:

Attach the disks and partition them with the new bigger partitions.
Add the 2 new disks to the array and sync them
Install grub on the new disks
Remove the old one from the array and boot on the new ones.


I don't know this would work, and I would be extremely dubious about "Attach the disks and format them like the actual ones" step.   You don't format disks when using software RAID, you expand the underlying partitions then resize the RAID then expand the filesystem on the RAID.
I'm hesitant to provide an answer for this use case because you are going from 2TB disks to something larger.  Often 2TB Disks are using MBR partitioning rather then GPT and I fear that going from 1 to the other could cause boot issues.  Ignoring this elephant in the room though -
I would partition the new disks so they are as big as you can.  I'd then remove one of the old disks from the array and put in the new disk.    I'd rebuild the array with the new disk.
Once the above is complete I'd do the same with the other disk.
The next step would be to grow the array using mdadm --grow /dev/mdX
I'd then re-install GRUB on each of the disks using grub-install (on the /dev/sdX - not on the mdadm device) and grow the filesystem - I assume using xfs_growfs

Bad wording by me I guess. I meant to partition, not format, the disk with the same partition table. Basically doing sfdisk -d /dev/sdX | sfdisk /dev/sdY. I'm using GPT already.

Just make sure the start blocks ate the same - the actual partitions should be the full size of the new disk

If I used the partitions when I created the array  with mdadm (ie. nvmen1p1->nvmen2p1), can I move the partitions around in the new disk as long as they are identical size and just add the new partitions to the old array? Or they must start at the same blocks even in this case. I'm asking because I would like to resize also a partition in the middle (the 2nd of 4 partitions).

You can move partitions around.  The idea behind having the same start point is so you can simply use fdisk to quickly grow the partition - where if you change the start point of the partition you need to realign the contents which is slower and requires additional software or hardware. Partitions don't need to be the same size - they can be larger (but not smaller unless you first shrink the filesystem)

Let's say I have sda1\2\3\4, all mirrored with mdadm and want to switch to a bigger sdb.What I want to do is cloning sda1\sda3 by creating and identical partition on sdb1\sdb3 and adding it to the original array. then manually create sdb2, bigger and leave it there (it's just a swap). Then create again sdb4 identical to sda4, clone it by adding to original array. Then resize sda4 array with mdadm and resize the sdb4 to fill the remaining size with resizefs.

sdb3 and sdb4 Will have a different starting block, because sdb2 will be bigger. I just want to make sure I can still add them to the original sda mdadm array to mirror them even if they have different starting block. Once I have the mirror I would just fail the sdaX ones and resize the new resulting array on the new disk.

mdadm does not care about offsets or disk layouts - it just cares that it knows the block device.   (It is even possible to use mdadm on an unpartitioned disk).

You don't need the partitition number to be the same - ie you can have sda1 and change to sdb4 and that will still work fine with mdadm.    If you are redoing your filesystem you may want to consider getting rid of the swap disk and converting it to a swap file as it makes management easier, and seems to have become the prefered way of doing it.

I've read too many cons to having a swap file than pros, so I just keep a partition (it doesn't impact anyway on the total space when we speak about TB). So if it doesn't matter WHERE they start I can just repartition as I want the new ones, as long as they have at least the same size, and grow the array when adding them. I will then remove the old ones from the array when they are synced. I just need to rememebr to install grub on all and update initramfs. Correct?

Yup.  You only need to grow the array when all partitions have been expanded and you want to take advantage of the extra space.

By "growing" I mean mdadm grow --raid-devices=4 to sync them. Then I first remove the old disks and then resize the array and filesystem.

I am not an expert with exactly that - I have not played with syncing 4 devices on RAID1 - its more normal to fail 1 disk, then replace it, then fail the second, replace it, then grow the disk.  There is every possibility you could make this work - but I don't know how practical it is to shrink the number of devices in a RAID array.  That said it appears https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/640796/mdadm-raid1-can-you-grow-to-3-disks-then-revert-back-to-2 that you can shrink an array by growing it to 2 devices.

Perfect. That link was the answer I was looking for but couldn't find. So, if mdadm doesn't actually care where each partition start\stop on disk as long as they have the same size (because I want to resize the 2nd one), I think I have the complete solution.

Yes.  Partitions don't even need to be the same size - they just need to be no smaller then the old ones.  If they are larger you can then grow the raid and filesystem to expand to the space (and I am fairly sure MDADM will expand it to the size of the smallest partition if the partition sizes are not identical)
